# Is there a way to set up a TileBrush so that it's always 1 tile high, but a variable amount of tiles wide?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm attempting to make a `TileBrush` that, when used, will always be one tile high and a variable amount of tiles wide (depending on how much space the element that it's applied to has).

To help illustrate my question, I've written a bit of code. In said code, there are two `TextBlock`s in a `Grid`. Both `TextBlock`s have the same background, but different font sizes. Currently, each `TextBlock`'s background is always 1 tile high and 4 tiles wide.

What change(s) would I need to make in order for each `TextBlock`'s background always to always be 1 tile high, but a variable amount of tiles wide (depending on the font size of the `TextBlock` and the width of its containing `Grid` column)?

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApp01.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTestApp01"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>

        <DrawingBrush x:Key="TestBrush"
                      TileMode="Tile"
                      Stretch="Uniform"
                      Viewbox="0,0,1,1"
                      ViewboxUnits="RelativeToBoundingBox"
                      Viewport="0,0,0.25,1"
                      ViewportUnits="RelativeToBoundingBox">
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <GeometryGroup>
                            <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50"
                                             RadiusX="20"
                                             RadiusY="45"/>
                            <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50"
                                             RadiusX="45"
                                             RadiusY="20"/>
                        </GeometryGroup>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" />
                    </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <Pen Thickness="2"
                             Brush="Black"/>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      Grid.RowSpan="2"
                      Width="3"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      Background="Black"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Left text here."
                   FontSize="12"
                   FontFamily="Consolas"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Background="{StaticResource TestBrush}"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Right text here."
                   FontSize="30"
                   FontFamily="Consolas"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   Background="{StaticResource TestBrush}"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here's what the above code produces:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your brush tiles four across because you've set the viewport exactly to 1/4 the relative size of the output bounding box. As long as the viewport has this fixed relationship to the bounding box, you can't get anything *other* than four across.

So, the way to fix this is to remove that relationship and replace it with something more appropriate. The simplest way to do that is of course to set the viewport mode to `Absolute` instead of `RelativeToBoundingBox`. But then the question is, what absolute value to use? In the code you posted, if you set the absolute size to any specific fixed value, you'll get the same size anywhere you use the brush, and it won't fit in the `TextBlock` you want.

What you need is a different size depending on the `TextBlock`. This means a different brush for each `TextBlock`. But, you probably don't want to have to declare a new brush for every `TextBlock` you declare, hard-coding the size to fit. For that matter, maybe you don't even want to declare a new `TextBlock`. WPF works much better when you use templates to arrange the visual tree. Using a template allows you to hard-code the aspects you want to repeat everywhere, while still allowing the context of the visual element to control specific aspects that need to vary. So, let's do that!

First, you'll need a view model:

```cs
class TextAndSizeModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public double Size { get; set; }
}
```

This is a degenerate model, containing just the two pieces of data that varies in your example, with no property-change notification. We're not going to change the values in this simple example, so that's fine.

Now, one of the less-obvious things you'll need is a converter. This is because we want a different viewport size in each case, and the viewport size is a `Rect`, which is a simple value, not a dependency object. So we need a converter to make an appropriate `Rect` value as needed:

```cs
class SquareRectConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double doubleValue = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);

        return new Rect(0, 0, doubleValue, doubleValue);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And now we're ready to do the markup. It looks like this:

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestSO61021208TileBrush.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestSO61021208TileBrush"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <Window.Resources>
    <GeometryDrawing x:Key="geometryDrawing1">
      <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        <GeometryGroup>
          <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50"
                                             RadiusX="20"
                                             RadiusY="45"/>
          <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50"
                                             RadiusX="45"
                                             RadiusY="20"/>
        </GeometryGroup>
      </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
      <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" />
      </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
      <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
        <Pen Thickness="2"
                             Brush="Black"/>
      </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
    </GeometryDrawing>

    <local:SquareRectConverter x:Key="squareRectConverter1"/>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TextAndSizeModel}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
                  FontSize="{Binding Size}"
                  FontFamily="Consolas">
        <TextBlock.Background>
          <DrawingBrush
                  TileMode="Tile"
                  Stretch="Uniform"
                  Viewbox="0,0,1,1"
                  ViewboxUnits="RelativeToBoundingBox"
                  Viewport="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBlock}, Converter={StaticResource squareRectConverter1}}"
                  ViewportUnits="Absolute"
                  Drawing="{StaticResource geometryDrawing1}"/>
        </TextBlock.Background>
      </TextBlock>                   
    </DataTemplate>

  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      Grid.RowSpan="2"
                      Width="3"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      Background="Black"/>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
      <ContentControl.Content>
        <local:TextAndSizeModel Text="Left text here." Size="12"/>
      </ContentControl.Content>
    </ContentControl>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
      <ContentControl.Content>
        <local:TextAndSizeModel Text="Right text here." Size="30"/>
      </ContentControl.Content>
    </ContentControl>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

`ContentControl` is used, of course, to map the view model object to the template. You'll see in the template three bindings:

1. The text value.
2. The font size value.
3. The `ActualHeight` of the containing `TextBlock` element to the `Viewport` size value, via the converter

This sets the height of the viewport to exactly the height of the `TextBlock`. But it also allows the viewport to be a square that is not relative to the bounding box, so that it can tile properly across the entire background.

The result looks like this:
[image]

Now the brush tiles horizontally to fit the background, no matter the actual width of the `TextBlock`.

Of course, in this particular example the brush changes height according to the size of the `TextBlock`. I inferred that was what you wanted because that's how it works in your original example, and you didn't write anything to suggest you wanted it otherwise. However, you should be able to modify the basic technique above to get what you want. You'll need to do the math differently, so that instead of making the height and width vary exactly with the height of the containing element, you decide on a fixed width for the brush, using the passed-in height only for the height of the viewport. In this way the brush will be centered vertically in the element with a fixed size for the graphic element, while still tiled horizontally.

That would look something like this:

**Converter:**

```cs
class CenteredRectConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double height = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
        double width = System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter);

        return new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Data template:**

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TextAndSizeModel}">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
              FontSize="{Binding Size}"
              FontFamily="Consolas">
    <TextBlock.Background>
      <DrawingBrush
              TileMode="Tile"
              Stretch="Uniform"
              Viewbox="0,0,1,1"
              ViewboxUnits="RelativeToBoundingBox"
              Viewport="{Binding ActualHeight,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBlock},
                Converter={StaticResource centeredRectConverter1},
                ConverterParameter=14}"
              ViewportUnits="Absolute"
              Drawing="{StaticResource geometryDrawing1}"/>
    </TextBlock.Background>
  </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

That looks like this instead:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! The first example you gave is exactly what I was looking for -- where the brush stretches vertically to fit the height of the `TextBlock`. I appreciate the second example as well, since I wasn't clear about that aspect of how I wanted the brush to behave.